# How do I choose the best color profile for a LG external monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, settings, color

I recently bought a LG monitor 22MP55, to use at home as a second monitor with my MacBook Pro.

But the color is a little weird! Slightly yellowish.

I tried using it with a Windows 7 PC with the same website, and the colors displayed with the PC windows were more accurate and better.

Why is the display color better with a Windows PC? How can I get a better colour profile on my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is adjust the color profile on your Macbook Pro to take advantage of the LG 22MP55. So you would go to `System Preferences -> Displays` and then choose `Color` and play around with the selected `Display profile:` to find one that suits your needs best.

Or you can take it a step further by calibrating your own profile. Which can be tricky, but does work if you spend the time and effort.  In that same preference area choose `Calibrate…` to begin the process of adjusting your screen settings to best suit your needs.

But past any of that, you might find it worth it to invest in a calibration device such as a Spyder calibrator. I use the Spyder3EXPRESS and it works great. The newest version is the [Spyder4EXPRESS](http://spyder.datacolor.com/portfolio-view/spyder4express/) which should be just as good if not better. It costs anywhere from $60 to $99 and is well worth the investment. The color on your display will be perfectly calibrated with little hassle or headache.

Answer (score 2):

I found turning HDR off in the mac settings for the display did wonders. It otherwise looks all washed out.

Comment: Mine had a reddish glow in some spots that also disappeared when turning off High Dynamic Range (HDR) in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a application on your Mac that allows displays color management.

It is in your Utility folder called ColorSync Utility.

Open it and look what profile is used currently, and what is he factory recommended profile.

Here you can choose different color profiles or modify the existing ones to one that suits you.

Answer (score -2):

If your monitor's reader profile is on, please switch that off. It will make a difference.